# What kind of query creates an olympic ranking (gold > silver > brass)?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

I want to make an olympic medal ranking.
Right now I have a pivot table that has a CountryID, MatchID and Medal column.
The medal column stores the values 1 (gold), 2 (silver) and three (brass).

Countries with the most gold should be the heighest in the rank, followed by the most silver etc. Only thing is, when gold is equal then the amount of silver medals should be taken in account and ofcourse if that is also equal compare brass medals.

Right now I take the following (not successful) approach:
First I make 3 queries like this to get an overview of the amount of medals per country:

```
var resGold = context.olympics_landen_wedstrijd.Where(n => n.medal ==   1).GroupBy(n => n.LandID).Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Medal = 2 }).OrderByDescending(n => n.Count);
```

Then I combine resGold, resSilver and resBrass into one list. That list I query again to get a ranking where countries with the most gold are ranked higher.

```
var list = all.OrderBy(t => t.Medal == 1 ? 1 : (t.Medal == 2 ? 2 : t.Medal == 3 ? 3 : 4)).ToList();
```

The problem is that I end up with a list where countries are ranked more then once. When Germany and the USA both have 10 golden medals and they both also have silver medals then there is another record for both countries in the list.

How can I achieve to get a ranking according to olympic standards with my database setup?

The result I'm looking to create is:

[RANK 1] CountryID = 2, numberofGold = 10, numberofSilver = 3, numberOfBrass = 5 
[RANK 2] CountryID = 3, numberofGold = 10, numberofSilver = 9, numberOfBrass = 9 
[RANK 3] CountryID = 4, numberofGold = 9, numberofSilver = 10, numberOfBrass = 10 
....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is already a pivot table

Comment: The evaluation can be based on score gold:silver:bronz =5:3:1(weighted ranking), review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_medal_table

Comment: Wow nice, didn't knew worked like that! Saved my day! :)

Comment: Welcome. Glad for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute score for every country based in Weighted Rank.

The ratio can be gold:silver:bronz = 5:3:1

you can sort country based on score Desc

Review

[Olympic medal table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_medal_table)

Comment: I have to argue with that solution. Mathematically it sound okay. But, when counting olympic medal rankings, when the Olympic rankings are compiled, typically the ranking is not weighted, but based on the absolute priority of medals. What I mean:
If Country A has 5 gold, 4 silver 1 bronze, and country B has 6 gold, 1 silver, 0 bronze, and C has 1 gold, 22 silver, 10 bronze, than the weighted order would be:
A, C, B
But, with what I call "absolute priority of medals" the order is: B, A, C. And this is more often used.
This site illustrates my point:
https://www.olympicmedalrankings.com/